# Correlation plot with slop area

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression, correlation, confidence-interval

I have the number of mutations accumulated by age and the median number of mutations in a given age like below

```
> dput(head(data))
structure(list(Age = c(44, 44.8, 47.5, 48.1, 48.8, 50.2), Mutations = c(326.2411348, 
218.7943262, 882.9787234, 361.7021277, 901.0638298, 742.1985816
), Age.group = c(40L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50L), Median.of.mutation.per.age.group = c(576.2411348, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 374.4680851)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

I want a plot like this

[image]

***Where each dot represents the median number of mutations from individuals of a given age (like 40,50,60,70 years old). Red and green lines show best estimates for the slopes (that is mutations accumulated with time); 95% confidence intervals for the slopes are shown in lighter green and lighter red shading.***

I have tried this

```
cor.test(c(40,50,60,70),c(576.2411348,374.4680851,352.8368794,425.5319149))

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  c(40, 50, 60, 70) and c(576.2411348, 374.4680851, 352.8368794, 425.5319149)
t = -1.0812, df = 2, p-value = 0.3927
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.9903522  0.8497519
sample estimates:
       cor 
-0.6073455
```

Which gives the below far from what I need really

[image]

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_smooth()` in the `ggplot2` package.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Age, y = Mutations)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

You can pass other parameters to `geom_point()` and `geom_smooth()` to control their behavior. You can also customize the ggplot object in a lot of other ways. Look for a ggplot tutorial on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much, is there any way to show p-value and slop here in the plot? Slop should calculated by all mutations not only the median number for each age category